# Resources not found exception loading drawable animation into image view

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I'm trying to animate an image view that I'm using as a background in my activity but the app crashes when loading the activity. All the images and the .xml file are in the drawable-hdpi folder so I'm not sure why it's not finding it. Please let me know if there is a better way to set an animation as an activity background.

Heres my .xml file for the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow1" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow2" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow3" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow4" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow5" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow6" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow7" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow8" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bow9" android:duration="60" />
</animation-list>
```

Heres the code I'm using to try run it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView bground;
AnimationDrawable bganim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bground = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.background);
    bground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bowanimbg);
    bganim = (AnimationDrawable) bground.getBackground();
    bganim.start();
}
```

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lucidity/com.example.lucidity.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi/bowanimbg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000b`

Comment: Please cross check the spelling once.

Comment: I have checked multiple times it is all correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it!! Since it wasn't loading the animation at all I decided to make an onWindowFocusedChanged method so that it would load the animation once the activity had loaded. I also set the background of the imageview to my bowanimbg.xml file in the .xml which I initially thought wouldn't be necessary.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
bground = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.background);
bground.setImageResource(R.drawable.bowanimbg);
bganim = (AnimationDrawable) bground.getBackground();
if (hasFocus) {
    bganim.start();
} 
else {
    bganim.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a comment, but unfortunately I don't have a high enough rep. So I'll do my best to solve the problem.

You mentioned that all of the images were present in the `drawable-hdpi` folder. But if you notice the error, it looks like it is searching for the file in the `res/drawable-xxhdpi` folder. What I would suggest is copying the `.xml` files from the `-hdpi` folder into the `-xxhdpi` folder and seeing if it works!